# aws s3 sdk has same or equivalent command as aws s3 cp?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Pretty much as the question is, does the `aws s3 sdk`  has same or equivalent command as `aws s3 cp`?

running `aws s3 cp` on terminal with `recursive` is able to copy all the files locally but if I want to do that through `aws s3 sdk` is it possible?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / help.

Comment: Looks like there isn't option like that. According to github code of [cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli). You will have iterate through response of `list-objects-v2` which returns paginated response of all objects and prefixes and download them with `get-object` operation.

Comment: @Imran I did see this and thought of iterate through but then what is bothering is if there are subfolders :( thought there might be something new that I am missing

Answer (score 1):

The [`aws s3api`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html) commands are exactly equivalent to AWS SDK calls. They are a 1:1 match.

The [`aws s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) commands are convenience commands provided by the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) that make it easier to use S3, such as providing sync, move and recursive capabilities. These are achieved by code *within* the AWS CLI rather than matching an API call.

Comment: do you have an example of the `sdk` in `js` for recursive copy everything in folder and sub folders?

Comment: There is no such capability in any of the SDKs. It has been provided as part of the AWS CLI, which uses the Python SDK plus extra code.